# Finding successor chips

Tags: integrated-circuit

When you find out that a chip you were interested in is obsolete, and no longer made, how do you figure out which chips have replaced it?

I've been having great fun getting hands-on experience with different chips in the 74xx series: plugging them each into a breadboard with a microprocessor, and making a sample project with each.

As I look down the list of 74xx chips, it's clear that some of them have not been made in ages, because they've been completely obsoleted by more recent chips and concepts.

I want to explore the current set of commonly-used parts. If a chip has been replaced by something that gets the job done better, I want to play with that new thing. How would you figure out what that thing is?

For example, the 74116 chip sounds interesting. A simple, no-frills latch? I can see uses for that. But clearly, something better has come along, because as best I can tell, no one makes that chip any more. What's a good way to figure out what has replaced it?

Comment: Hmm. This question may end up flirting with 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion-based' classification and close-votes, despite it being an interesting discussion topic.

Comment: The original 74xx bipolar TTL logic parts have generally been replaced by the 74LSxx and 74ALSxx families, and by their CMOS equivalents 74HCxx, 74ACxx and similar families.

Comment: Peter: Good point. But in some cases the whole idea of a chip is obsolete, and it's not clear what new idea came along to replace it. Take the example of the 74116, above. It's not available as an HC, LS, or whatever else.

Comment: For the record, NTE still lists the 74116 in their inventory.

Comment: @RDrast That's kind of like saying they're still in stock at the antique shop. NTE for service replacement and Rochester and a few others for NOS at 'I'll pay anything' prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few general obsolescence strategies.

1. Check the original manufacturer's website and look up the PCN (product change notice). Most big manufacturers will publish these any time there's a meaningful change to a part (new rev, new fab, end-of-life, last-time-buy, withdrawn, etc. They sometimes recommend fit-form-function replacements or migration paths to new devices.
2. Check other manufacturers and see if there's a cross-reference for the obsolete part (or one of it's manufacturer-suggested alternates).
3. Do parametric searches for parts in the same family (i.e. opamp) specify the specific (no pun intended) parameters that most concern you (packaging, pinout, power, capacitance, etc.) and see what you get.